Connecting a C wire to an old furnace

Where is the recommended place to connect a C line for a smart thermostat?
I'll use the blue line,  and other responses have me looking at splicing into the transformer blue wire.
g

Yes, you've understood the other question/answers correctly. According to the wiring diagram you posted the blue wire from the transformer is the common. A small clue of this is that the blue wire goes to both the gas valve and the control board. A bigger clue is that the blue wire is shown attaching to ground, ie the metal furnace chassis.
It might be easy, and obvious to the next person who works in your furnace, if you connect the blue thermostat wire under the same screw where the blue transformer wire attaches to the furnace.

